# Alterar Fonte do Prompt de Comando

Tags: ms-dos

Existe alguma linha de comando para alterar a fonte que é exibida em uma janela do cmd? Apenas nesta janela? Alterando pelo menu propriedades ele altera em geral.

Comment: No *Windows 10*, basta alterar em propriedades. Após fazer isso, basta abrir um novo terminal > configurar a fonte para o padrão e fechar. Dessa forma apenas uma janela será alterada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clique no campo de pesquisa do Windows 10 e digite cmd, clique no resultado para abrir o Prompt de comando;
2. Clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre a barra superior do Prompt e escolha a opção Propriedades;
3. Na aba Opções é possível customizar o tamanho do cursor, histórico de comandos, opções de edição e seleção de texto;
4. Na aba Fonte é possível alterar o tamanho da fonte usada e a fonte padrão;
5. Em Layout é possível alterar o tamanho do buffer de tela, tamanho da janela e posição;
6. Em Cores o usuário pode alterar a cor de texto na tela, tela de fundo, texto pop-up, tela de fundo do pop-up e opacidade da cor escolhida.

**Realmente ele irá alterar para todas as janelas, não é possível mudar apenas para uma janela, é como o Notepad++.**

Comment: Entendi, mas não queria alterar em todas, queria uma linha de comando que alterasse apenas na janela atual, mas obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: É, infelizmente da forma que precisa não vai conseguir através do CMD do Windows =(